# How to disable and after enable the click receiving...?

Tags: c#

I wanna reset the MouseEventArgs to always run only once.
If somebody click the button more than once (10 times) then the program run 10x and so on.

My code doesn't work well, because if someone click on the button1 2x or more times it will be runned.
I wanna reset the MouseEventArgs or do other solution.

Windows Form Application (XP, 32bit)

```
    private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        button1.Enabled = false;
        button1.MouseClick -= button1_MouseClick;
        mc++;


        if (true)
        {
            button1.Enabled = false;
            //button1.Location = new Point(40, 40);
            //Point location = button1.Location;
            //location.X = 0; location.Y = 0;
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (mc == 1)
            {

                //button1.Location = new Point(67, 191);
                //location.X = 67; location.Y = 191;
                mc = 0;
                button1.Enabled = true;
                button1.MouseClick += button1_MouseClick;

                textBox1.AppendText("Click " + e.Clicks + ", Clicks: " + mc + "\n");

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You may just create a bool that indicates, if the code has already been executed instead of mutating the Event itself. Classic XY problem though :) Btw.: why are you re-assigning (or appending) the event-handler-method to the button? Ommit this line.

Comment: Because I wanna allow it after the System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); is runned.
I wanna allow only once click at once.

Comment: So you want the button to be disabled for 2seconds after being clicked and afterwards to be enabled again to receive further clicks?

Comment: Yes. :))
But the button will be not able to receive more than one click.
Because the button receives more than one click the code will be run more times.
And I wanna only one click and one running after I pressed/clicked the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute some long running job on the main thread.
It might look like you disabled the button and following clicks should be ignored but they are actually placed in a queue. If you take a look at the events queue every click is done when the button is enabled:

```
Click
Disable button
Wait 2 seconds
Enable button
Click
...
```

Try the following code:

```
private void button1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
        //disable button on main thread
        button1.Enabled = false;

        Thread worker = new Thread(() =>
        {
           //do time consuming job
           System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);

           //enable button (from the main thread)
           this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
           {
              textBox1.AppendText("Click " + e.Clicks + "\n");
              button1.Enabled = true;
           });
        });

        worker.Name = "Button 1 worker";
        worker.Start();
}
```

Now the time consuming job is done on separate thread and the UI events will work as expected:

```
Click
Disable button
Do job on another thread ------------> Wait 2 seconds
Click - ignored (button is disabled)        |
Click - ignored (button is disabled)        |
Click - ignored (button is disabled)        |
Click - ignored (button is disabled)        |                                                    
                                       Enable button
Click
Disable button ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing logic inside the event try to make a custom control that extend System.Windows.Forms.Button.

But as far as I can understand your code make you click event handler always be linked with the function, if mc value start with 0.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

When you disabled your button is may not receive any mouse-events further so you do not have to change any event-handlers. Write your code that should be executed once within your handler and disable the button. Thus the code cannot be executed any longer as long as the button is disabled.

Comment: I don't wanna disable the button forever just the clicks untill the Thread.Sleep running.

Comment: @RohlandHE Well, you could also implement a timer on your form with a duration of 2seconds, Always when this timer is executed you check if your button is disabled and if so you enable it. It gets then disabled again on next click on the button.